# forrtl: severe (38) error during write - python 2.7 statsmodels 0.6.1 during ARMA fit

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels

I'm trying to reproduce one of the statsmodels ARMA examples on the official site:
[ARMA example](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma.html) 
But executing the line:

`arma_mod20 = sm.tsa.ARMA(dta, (2,0)).fit()`

the interface throws the following error:

[image: Error window]

I'm using python 2.7 and the statsmodels version 0.6.1 and my OS is windows 7.
The solutions that already exist for this are for Fortran and trying some of them didn't solve my problem.

I really don't have a clue what is causing this error.

Comment: run the scipy unit tests, at least for optimize and linalg. My guess would be that there is something not correctly compiled in scipy optimize lbfgsb. However, I have no clue about Fortran or other non-python build and compiler problems. The ARMA code has cython in it's core, but I have never heard of a problem and that code hasn't changed in several years.

Comment: Reading the header of the message again. I think there might be a problem with lbfgsb trying to write the log file, which might not be possible with insufficient permission. Try `ARMA(...).fit(iprint=-1)` which is supposed to turn off the logfile printing. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html (I'm using Windows 7 and Windows 8 and don't have problems)

Comment: You are right user333700. I tried with the ARMA's parameter to omit logs:
arma_mod20 = sm.tsa.ARMA(dta, (2,0)).fit(disp=-1)
And it runs perfectly. I mean, it's not a proper solution but for my purpose it gets the job done. Thank you.